# Did pagan tribes use bells in their worship?

Tags: history, shirk

I read that pagans in the time of the Prophet (PBUH) would use bells in their worship rituals, as well as for protection from the evil eye. Does anyone have information on whether bells were prominent worship intruments?

Comment: how is this question Islam related? Maybe the History stack exchange site is more appropriate. Here is a link just in case you are interested: https://history.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is some information I have found so far:

> "About Removing Collars and Bells to get Rid of Magic Spells
>
> 1. 'Abbad ibn Tamim says that Abu Bashir Ansari told him that once he was with the Prophet (sws) on a journey. The Prophet (sws) sent a man (and 'Abdullah ibn Abi Bakr says that he thought that 'Abbad said that people were resting after a meal), and told him not to leave any camel without having his collar cut. Yahya says that he heard from Imam Malik that he thought this instruction was related to the collars which people placed to protect their animals from the evil eye."

http://www.al-mawrid.org/index.php/articles/view/muatta-imam-malik-6

If anyone has more information, please let me know.